# Pseudo-isomorphism in Iwasawa Theory

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\Lambda$ denote the Iwasawa algebra $\mathbb{Z}_p[[\Gamma]]$, where $\Gamma$ is a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$. We know that $\Lambda$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$, ring of power series in the variable $T$. Two modules $\Lambda$-modules $A$ and $B$ are said to be pseudo-isomorphic if there is a $\Lambda$-homomorphism $f\colon A\to B$ with finite kernel and cokernel, i.e. they sit in an exact sequence like $$0\to F_1\to A\to B\to F_2\to 0,$$ with $F_1$ and $F_2$ finite $\Lambda$-modules. We write $A\sim B$. If $A$ is finitely generated, then $$A\sim \Lambda^{n}\oplus \bigoplus_i \Lambda/f_i\Lambda$$ for some $f_i\in \Lambda$. The characteristic ideal is $\prod_i f_i\Lambda$.

I have a few questions:

1) Some authors define the characteristic ideal to be 0 in the non-torsion case, others does not specify. Is there a reason for which one is preferable? Is true in every case that the characteristic ideal well-behaves under exact sequences?

2) The pseudo-isomorphism relation is not symmetric in general, but it is in the case of torsion modules. Is there a simple way to see this?

3)Is this relation transitive in general, or maybe just in the case of torsion? No book says something like this, but if it is not symmetric, how can we say that if $A$ and $B$ are pseudo-isomorphic, then they have the same characteristic ideal?

For (3), it seems to me natural that if $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to C$ have finite kernel and cokernel, also the composition has finite kernel and cokernel. For example, the kernel of the composition is the set of elements going to zero under $f$, plus the ones going to the kernel of $g$, and also this second part is finite since both kernels are finite. Am I missing something?

Comment: If you mean $\mathbb{Z}_p[[\Gamma]]\cong \mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$, we just identify $1+T$ with a topological generator $\gamma$ of $\Gamma$...

Comment: I don't see. What is your homemorphism

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean? The homeomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_p[[T]]$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p[[\Gamma]]$ is well-know, and probably we don't need it explicitly for these questions. It is obtained as I told in the previous comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) *Characteristic ideal.* There is no need to define anything like a characteristic ideal (or polynomial) for a free $\Lambda$-module for the simple reason that there is no simpler object than a free object (in a relevant category). For a noetherian *torsion* $\Lambda$-module $M$, the utility of the ch. s. is that it somehow plays the role  of the determinant in linear algebra. However the genuine deep meaning, for certain $M$'s coming from arithmetic (such as the projective limit of the p-class groups when climbing up the p-cyclotomic tower) is that the ch. s. is intimately related to an adequate p-adic zeta function ("Main Conjecture" of Iw. theory). Given a short exact sequence of torsion $\Lambda$-modules, the ch. ideal of the middle term is the product of those of the extreme terms.

2) *Symmetry.* It is not so straihgtforward to show that pseudo-isomorphim between two torsion $\Lambda$-modules is a symmetric relation. The fastest proof I know uses the *uniqueness* of the decompostion up to pseudo-isomorphism of such a module into a direct sum of modules of the form $\Lambda /P^n$, where $P$ is a prime ideal of height 1.This can be done by hand, but you can also consult Serre's Bourbaki talk, "Classes des corps cyclotomiques"'1960), lemma 5 and thm.7.

3) *Transtivity* is easily reduced to the case of torsion modules. Then the approach is the same as in 2).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Just a clarification. If the module is free, then there is no reason to define the characteristic ideal. But if is not free, but is also not torsion, so it has a free part, what do you do? Still don't define it, or set it as 0, or take the characteristic ideal of its torsion part?

Comment: Also, can I ask another question? If $M$ is a finitely generated $\Lambda$-module such that $M_{\Gamma_n}$ is finite, where $\Gamma_n$ is the subgroup of $\Gamma_n$ with index $p^n$, and $M_{\Gamma_n}$ is the maximal quotient of $M$ on which $\Gamma_n$ acts trivial, then why $M$ has to be torsion?

Comment: About the second question. $\gamma^{p^n}$ is a generator of $\Gamma_n$. Then $M_{\Gamma_n}=M/(\gamma^{p^n}-1)M\cong M/((T+1)^{p^n}-1)M$ using the homeomorphism $\gamma\mapsto T+1$. $M$ is pseudoisomorphic to a module as in the second equation of your question.  If $M/((T+1)^{p^n}-1)M$ is finite, then every factor of the decomposition up to pseudoisomorphism, divided by $(T+1)^{p^n}-1$, must be finite, and hence also the factors $\Lambda/((T+1)^{p^n}-1)\Lambda$ that come from the torsion-free part. But $\Lambda/((T+1)^{p^n}-1)\Lambda$ is infinite since $(T+1)^{p^n}-1$ is not invertible.

Comment: @LStefanello.  *About your second query*. For a $\Lambda$-module $M$ : (1) $M$ is noetherian iff $\mathbf Z_p-rank(M_{\Gamma_n})$ is finite for all $n$ ; (2) $M$ is torsion iff $\mathbf Z_p-rank(M_{\Gamma_n})$ is bounded for all $n$ ; (3) $M$ is torsion with $\mu=0$ iff $\mathbf F_p-rank(M_{\Gamma_n})$ is bounded for all $n$.

Comment: *About your first query*. According to the structure theorem, the quotient $ M/\Lambda-torsion$ injects into a $\Lambda$-free module, with a finite cokernel $F(M)$, so the notion of ch. s. is irrelevant for both $M$ and $F(M)$. Nevertheless $F(m)$ has its own interest in applications to arithmetic. Take e.g. the $\Lambda$-module $X$ introduced in my main answer, usually called the *unramified* Iw. module, which is torsion. Introduce its "companion" $Y$, the Iw. module *unramified outside (p)*, which is not torsion (I don't present these guys, but you can meet them e.g. in Washington's book).

Comment: Then F(Y) and the maximal finite submodule of X are mutually in Kummer duality. This is a manifestation (not easy) of the so called Spiegelung (mirror) phenomenom.