# Invariants of Iwasawa Modules

Tags: modules, algebraic-number-theory, galois-cohomology

Let $\Lambda$ denote Iwasawa algebra $\mathbb{Z}_p[[\Gamma]]$, where $\Gamma$ is a group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$(ring of $p$-adic integers) . The structure theorem of the Iwasawa module tells; If M is a finitely generated $\Lambda$-module, then

$$M \sim \Lambda^r \oplus \bigoplus_{i=1}^t \Lambda/p^{n_i} \oplus \bigoplus_{j=1}^s \Lambda/f_j^{m_j}$$
is a pseudo isomorphism (maps with finite kernel and cokernel). If $M$ is $\Lambda$-torsion (i.e $r=0$), then in most of the articles they define

- The characteristic ideal of $M$ is $\displaystyle \prod_j^s f_j\Lambda$.
- The $\mu$-invariant of $M$ is $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n n_i $.

Clearly, the definitions of both invariants are independent on $r$(rank). My question is:

- why do we need the torsion condition to define them?

I understand that most of the objects that appear in theory are torsion, but what are the drawbacks if we define them for a non-torsion f.g module?

Note: There is a similar thread [Pseudo-isomorphism in Iwasawa Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3692286/pseudo-isomorphism-in-iwasawa-theory) for Characteristic ideal, but the answer is not convincing to me.
Is there something I'm missing in that post?

Comment: If you don’t require torsion, you don’t get multiplicativity for characteristic ideals, consider eg the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \Lambda \overset{f}{\rightarrow} \Lambda \rightarrow \Lambda/f\Lambda \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: @Aphelli I understand that characteristic ideal does not behave properly with exact sequences. However, still, I can define characteristic ideals for non-torsion modules ( because the structure theorem holds for non-torsion modules as well).

Comment: I agree that you can define it. But how can you hope to do anything useful with it if it doesn’t even respect exact sequences?

Answer (score 1):

There is in fact a general definition of the $\mu$-invariant of a finitely generated $\Lambda$-module which is not necessarily torsion. The definition also works for more general groups, e.g., when considering multiple $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extensions. Bascially, you look at the torsion submodule. This is used in the recent literature, e.g. to describe Iwasawsa modules associated to Selmer and fine Selmer groups.

Let $G$ be a uniform pro-$p$ group of dimension $l$, i.e. there exists a filtration $G=G_0 \supseteq G_1 \supseteq \dots$ such that each $G_{i+1}$ is normal in $G_{i}$ and $G_i / G_{i+1} \cong (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^l$. For example, $G=\Gamma\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$ or $G=\mathbb{Z}_p^l$. Let $\Lambda=\mathbb{Z}_p[[G]]$ and let $M$ be a finitely generated $\Lambda$-module. Let $M(p)$ be the $p$-power torsion submodule of $M$. Then define

$$ \mu (M) = \sum_{i \geq 0} \text{rank}_{\mathbb{F}_p[[G]]} (p^i M(p) / p^{i+1} M(p) ) $$
(see [Howson, S.: Euler characteristics as invariants of Iwasawa modules. Proc. Lond. Math. Soc. 85(3), 634–658 (2002)](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/S0024611502013680)). Note that only finitely many terms in the above sum are nonzero. It is easy to see that this agrees with the classical definition of $\mu$ for $\mathbb{Z}_p[[\Gamma]]$-torsion modules.

Regarding exact sequences $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$, one has
$$ \mu(B) \leq \mu(A) + \mu(C)$$
with equality if the modules are torsion.